# Mongodb query and sort multiple collections

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I'm a new comer to MongoDB and I don't know how to deal with querying and sorting multiple collections just as mysql. There are two collections as below:

```
// Collection customer:
{"id":01, "name":"a", "age":18}
{"id":02, "name":"b", "age":17}
{"id":03, "name":"b", "age":22}

// Collection point:
{"id":01, "customer_id":"01", "point":50}
{"id":02, "customer_id":"01", "point":150}
{"id":03, "customer_id":"02", "point":150}
{"id":04, "customer_id":"02", "point":50}
{"id":05, "customer_id":"01", "point":150}
{"id":06, "customer_id":"03", "point":50}
{"id":07, "customer_id":"03", "point":150}
```

How to get query like mysql 'select a.id as id, a.point as point, b.age as age from point as a left join customer as b on a.customer_id = b.id order by age limit 0,5'

Comment: Not possible. Mongo does not support any kind of join syntax. If you need to run SQL queries - **use an RMDBS**!! In mongo, you would store the `point` _in the_ `customer` as a subdocument. This is power of Mongo - it is **not** a drop in replacement for an RMDBS that is somehow magically faster.

Comment: since mongodb 3.6 that's possible. see lookup operator

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB you query only one collection at once. 
As [**Boris the Spider**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011350/mongodb-query-and-sort-multiple-collections#comment57749921_35011350) mentioned, there are no kind of SQL joins in mongo.
You should combine queried data in your application logic.

Read more about MongoDB [data modeling concepts](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-models/) and typical [relationships](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/) between documents.

Also, [this blog post series](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/thinking-documents-part-1) demonstrates what **Rich Document Data Models** is.